# How to make a loop exit when EOF or '\n'?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, getchar

After I type my message and the array gets populated the loop will not exit, it will go back to wanting more input. My question is how to make this loop exit when the user is done entering their message and the array has been populated?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 100

int main(void){

int counter = 0;
char C, characterArray[MAX] = {0};

printf("Enter a message: ");

for (C = getchar(); C != EOF || '\n'; C = getchar()){

    characterArray[counter++] = C;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `C != EOF && C !='\n';`

Comment: Note that it should be `int C;` (or, more conventionally, `int c;`) since `getchar()` returns an `int`, not a `char`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you I will make that change :)

Comment: getchar returns an int.  EOF is an int.  in windows/dos, '\n' is two characters (can be represented in a int.)  so change 'char C' to 'int C'  The assignment of C to the characterArray[] will still work correctly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
C != EOF || '\n'
```

does not do what you think it does. It evaluates `C != EOF` then logical ORs *that* with `'\n'` (which is non-zero, so true) - it's equivalent to:

```
(C != EOF) || '\n'
```

What you *actually* need is:

```
(C != EOF) && (C != '\n'))
```

---

Three other points. First, you should also check to ensure that `counter` is not beyond the end of the array, lest you become inflicted with the effects of undefined behaviour.

Secondly, if you're going to ever treat that buffer as a string, make sure you null-terminate it. It's not important in *this* code segment since you're doing nothing with it. It may not even be necessary if you *do* use it as a string if, for example, you only get the data once (since the initialisation is zero-filling the buffer).

However, if you ever accept *more* than one line of input, you should terminate it as part of the input operation.

And thirdly, `C` should be an `int` rather than a `char`. The reason for this is that `getchar()` needs to be able to return any character *and* the `EOF` indicator.

---

The following code shows one way to do what you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 20

int main (void) {
    int c, counter = 0;
    char arr[MAX] = {0};

    printf("Enter a message: ");
    for (c = getchar();
        (c != EOF) && (c!= '\n') && (counter < MAX - 1);
        counter++, c = getchar())
    {
        arr[counter] = c;
    }
    arr[counter] = '\0';

    printf ("You entered: [%s]\n", arr);

    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, you could replace the `for` loop with something like:

```
counter = 0;
while ((counter < MAX - 1) && ((c = getchar()) != EOF) && (c != '\n'))
    arr[counter++] = c;
```

This uses the short-circuiting nature of `&&` to ensure each condition is met before testing the next.

Comment: Are You sure about the `&&` operator?

Comment: @sharon: pretty sure. It seems likely that the OP wants to stop at end of line or end of file.

Comment: So You are mentioning `or` But you have give the `&&` operator?

Comment: @sharon, it's negative logic as per De Morgan's law: `do while (char isn't EOF) and (char isn't  \n)` is the same as `do until (char is EOF) or (char is \n)`.

Comment: "C != (EOF || '\n')" -- this is wrong. The correct statement would be "(C != EOF) || ('\n')"

Answer (score 2):

Check the below changes

```
while( counter <MAX && ((C = getchar()) != EOF && C != '\n'))
{
  characterArray[counter++] = C;
}
```